# jQuery add class to elements of type if they are visible

Tags: jquery, svg

I have some SVG that I would like to animate if they are visible. In more technical way, I would want to add a class to object of x type if it is visible.

I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('circle').is(':visible')){
        $(this).addClass("animated fadeIn");
    }
});
```

However, without any success. What I wanted to achive for using this, is to add class to an object of type cricle, when it is visible. In other words - I want to apply the class only to the circles that are visible.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After the comments, I've tried the following:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('circle:visible').addClass("animated fadeIn");
})
```

However:

```
$('circle:visible')
```

is always empty array.

Comment: ^ It would be the `window`, not undefined. Either way, not intended behaviour

Comment: when you select all the elements with class 'curcle' -> $('.circle') do forEach on them and then check is the element visible

Comment: @VasilIndzhev `circle` is a valid SVG element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle

Comment: @VasilIndzhev, I dont want to select all the elements - I want to select only the one that is visible.

Comment: @SudharsanS Not `undefined` but a reference to `document`

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Just use `$('circle:visible').addClass("animated fadeIn");`

Comment: Ya Wolff provide the answer finally

Comment: @A.Wolff, for some reason, $('circle:visible') always returns empty array. I am updating my question

Comment: Come on Wolff I am waiting for your updated answer

Comment: @uksz Ok, i guess this is because how jQuery filtering it. It is designed to work on DOM element, not svg ones. Now depending how you hide them, if using `visibility attribute` (as you should), then try instead: `$('circle:not([visibility=hidden])').addClass(...)`

Comment: EDIT: now because i see you use `scroll` event, you should define what you call `visible`? You could mean instead 'displayed inside viewport' which then is a complete different thing